# Azure data factory - getting the HTTP Status of a web activity output

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a web activity calling a REST API in Azure Data Factory.
The @string(activity("web call").output ) returns what appears to be the output body, but i cannot see the http status (200, 404 etc)
I know the status code is returned as postman can see it.

How can i get the http status from a web activity output?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no direct activity or expression in ADF to capture the HTTP response from the Web Activity output.

As a workaround, you can achieve this by using custom code in Azure Function to capture response codes and you can call this function from `Web activity` ADF.