# Accessing REST API Status Codes using Azure Data Factory Copy Activity (or similar)?

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory

I'm calling a REST API endpoint via Azure Data Factory using copy activity.  The API returns 404 - not found for valid queries where no data is found.  Whether this is the appropriate response or not (I have no control over the API), is there a way to access the API status code (i.e. not Azure error code?) in ADF?

I want the pipeline to return 'success' when a 404 not found is returned, but still fail when other errors occur.  I have set up an 'on failure' error handling activity, but I'm getting stuck on how to distinguish between 'valid' errors & 404s due to no data.

[Activity output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpw41.png)

The error message string contains the status code (& response), which is what I'm after.  Ideally I'd like to compare against these without doing a string comparison, especially seeing as the message appears to be constructed using the exact response fields I'm after.

The 404 only occurs for some query parameters & the response is the same via Postman, so I'm relatively confident it is an intended response from the API.

Based on [Azure data factory - getting the HTTP Status of a web activity output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71556696/azure-data-factory-getting-the-http-status-of-a-web-activity-output) I'm not sure if this can be done exactly, but thought I'd (a) check & (b) see if anyone can suggest a better approach.